# PowerApps: Button click postback clears selected checkboxes

Tags: sharepoint-online

I customized a SharePoint form with PowerApps, it has a gallery with checkboxes so the user can select items which get added to a collection when pressing a button.

Works great within the PowerApps designer. However, when I publish to SharePoint the associated button click action causes a postback which clears all the checkboxes,  resulting in an empty collection.

I set the OnSelect properties of labels etc. within the gallery to false (instead of select parent), not sure what else to set to prevent postback from clearing the checkbox values selected by the user.

Suggestions?

Update: only happens with Chrome. IE handles it just fine.